# Multi client server in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets

I am writing a chat program between a server and a client in C# .Net. Both users, aside from chatting can engage in different activities like remote desktop and playing games together.

I have a few questions:

1. Multiple threads will be sending and receiving stuff from the client at the same time, that means every option need to identify which packet is meant for him and take data from it ? (Running a remote desktop while transferring a file a same time, the remote desktop thread will see the file packets arriving at stream but should ignore it, right?)
2. What's a good buffer size to set for the socket I will accept clients in?
3. Do I communicate in form of specialized class containing the data or try to keep the communication as a byte array I send over the stream?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65c848ca-537a-4494-b5e8-3509ea61c171/c-chat-application?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: How about Windows Communication Foundation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx

Comment: How about WebSockets? http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Comment: It's sad WCF is only for .Net 4.0, I am planning on using .Net 2.0.

Comment: WCF was introduced with .NET 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions 2 and 3 are impossible for us to answer because we don't know what the communication and the requirements look like.

As for handling multiple threads: that is hard to get right, I'd use an existing solution.

I suggest you have a look at [0MQ](http://zeromq.org/) as it might prevent you from reinventing the wheel.

There are .NET client libraries available: http://nzmq.codeplex.com/ and a nuget package http://www.nuget.org/packages/clrzmq/2.2.5 as well.

A good start is [The Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall)

For a quick example see [this C# server](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C#/hwserver.cs) and its [hello world client in C#](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs%3ahwclient)